# How do I put a list of id in an INNER JOIN with a sql variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I apologize in advance, I'm not good at sql.
I want to do something very simple in a sql procedure but I'm stuck :

`SELECT donnee.id_enregistrement, ',@col_createur, @col_date_creation, @col_date_derniere_modification, @COLUMNS
FROM ta_donnee_champ donnee`

In the variable @COLUMNS there is a list of id, that I search in the table "ta_donnee_champ donnee".

I also want to use the same list of id to search in another table in the same query.

How can I put that in an inner join?

Like something like this :

`SELECT donnee.id_enregistrement, ',@col_createur, @col_date_creation, @col_date_derniere_modification, @COLUMNS,'
FROM ta_donnee_champ donnee
INNER JOIN ta_champ_tableau ct
ON ct.id_champ_colonne IN (@COLUMNS)`

Can someone give me a simple explanation please?

******************************EDIT********************************

In this procedure @COLUMNS represents columns of the desired results.
To these columns, I need to add values, the following code works :

```
IF @COLUMNS IS NOT NULL THEN
SET @SQL = CONCAT(
       'SELECT donnee.id_enregistrement, ',@col_createur, @col_date_creation, @col_date_derniere_modification, @COLUMNS,'
       FROM ta_donnee_champ donnee
       INNER JOIN t_enregistrement enregistrement
       ON donnee.id_enregistrement = enregistrement.id_enregistrement
       WHERE donnee.id_enregistrement IN (',IFNULL(p_id_enregistrement, 'donnee.id_enregistrement'),')
       AND donnee.id_enregistrement in (
           select DISTINCT id_enregistrement from ta_participant
           where id_groupe = ', p_id_groupe,'
       or id_groupe in (
           select id_groupe_lu
       from ta_droits_groupe
       inner join t_groupe on ta_droits_groupe.id_groupe_lu = t_groupe.id_groupe
       where id_groupe_lecteur = ', p_id_groupe,'
       and t_groupe.id_application = ', p_id_application,'
     )

    )
       GROUP BY donnee.id_enregistrement'
);

-- Prépare et exécute la requête
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

My question is : I need to add another table from which I must know that ids are inside. How do I proceed best to search not only for id's in ta_donnee_champ donnee but also in another table?

How is @COLUMNS set :

```
SET @COLUMNS = NULL;

IF p_autoriser_tableau = 1 THEN
  SET @filtre = 'SELECT DISTINCT id_champ_colonne FROM ta_champ_tableau';
ELSE
  SET @filtre = 'SELECT DISTINCT id_champ_tableau AS id_champ FROM    ta_champ_tableau UNION SELECT DISTINCT id_champ_colonne FROM ta_champ_tableau';
END IF;

-- Construit les colonnes à  horizontaliser
SET @SQL1 = CONCAT('
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
           \'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(donnee.id_champ = \',
           champ.id_champ ,
           \', donnee.valeur, NULL)) AS `\',
           champ.id_champ,\'`\'
    )ORDER BY onglet.ordre, section.ordre, champ.ordre
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM t_champ champ
INNER JOIN t_section section
ON section.id_section = champ.id_section
INNER JOIN t_onglet onglet
ON onglet.id_onglet = section.id_onglet
INNER JOIN ta_droits_champ droits_champ
ON droits_champ.id_groupe IN (
SELECT id_groupe FROM ta_agent_groupe WHERE id_agent = ', p_id_agent,'
)
AND droits_champ.id_champ = champ.id_champ
where onglet.id_application IN (', p_id_application,')
AND droits_champ.voir = 1
AND champ.id_champ NOT IN (',@filtre,')
AND
(
champ.date_fin_validite IS NULL
OR
date_format(champ.date_fin_validite, "%Y-%m-%d") > COALESCE(str_to_date("', p_date_validite,'", "%d/%m/%Y"), "01/01/1900")
)
;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL1;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: Seems like you might need to use dynamic sql query.

Comment: What is `'` ???

Comment: I edited my post, I don't know if it's any more clear.

Comment: Is `@COLUMNS` a table variable, or a varchar? How is its value set?

Comment: @COLUMNS is a table variable